# PayPal Rest API with Billing Plan in ASP.NET MVC C# Posting Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, paypal

In July 2014, PayPal adding Billing Plans to their Rest API and had [examples](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements) by using cURL (only as of 8/5/2014).  They also mention it [here in a blog](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-rest-subscriptions-now-available/).  The issue is that I'm currently using the PayPal SDK for .NET and the **Billing Plans are not part of this SDK at this time**, so I have to manually create these POSTing connections.

**UPDATE:**  The issue(s) were a result from bad examples from the blog post on the topic of Billing Plans from PayPal.  Their API example, shows things like value and currency wrapped up in amount objects whereas the blog post did not and unfortunately that's what I started with.  I have updated the JSON example below for anyone else that needs a starting point for **Creating a Billing Plan against the PayPal REST API in C#.**

The error I was getting is a **"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."** when posting using the following code (below).  I am using their data to post, and pulling in my client Id and secret on the fly.  I get the ApiContext and my Access Token, so I'm authenticated prior to pushing data.

**Fiddler2 Returns the following (Raw data):**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbjava4.slc.paypal.com;threadId=21857
Paypal-Debug-Id: 9435d30090e68
SERVER_INFO: paymentsplatformserv:v1.payments.billing-plans&CalThreadId=26685&TopLevelTxnStartTime=147a6db17e2&Host=slcsbjm2.slc.paypal.com&pid=14241
Content-Language: *
Date: Tue, 05 Aug 2014 15:48:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 213
Connection: close

{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"9435d30090e68"}
```

**Json (updated since blog post values are incorrect)**
-- This passes Fiddler2 JSON parsing.

```
{ 
  "description" : "Template Creation",
  "merchant_preferences" : { 
      "auto_bill_amount" : "yes",
      "cancel_url" : "http://www.fruitofthemonth.com/cancel",
      "return_url" : "http://www.fruitofthemonth.com/complete",
      "setup_fee" : { 
          "currency" : "USD",
          "value" : "0"
      }
  },
  "name" : "Fast Speed Plan",
  "payment_definitions" : [ { 
      "amount" : { 
        "currency" : "USD",
        "value" : "100"
      },
      "charge_models" : [ { 
           "amount" : { 
              "currency" : "USD",
              "value" : "8"
           },
           "type" : "SHIPPING"
        },
        { 
            "amount" : { 
              "currency" : "USD",
              "value" : "4"
            },
          "type" : "TAX"
        }
      ],
    "cycles" : "12",
    "frequency" : "MONTH",
    "frequency_interval" : "2",
    "name" : "Standard Package",
    "type" : "REGULAR"
  } ],
 "type" : "fixed"
}
```

**C# (snippet - code below in a public class)**

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetConfiguration()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        configurationMap.Add("mode", "sandbox");
        return configurationMap;
    }  

    private string AccessToken
    {
        get
        {
            string token = new OAuthTokenCredential
                            (
                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalClientId"],
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalClientSecret"],
                                GetConfiguration()
                            ).GetAccessToken();
            return token;
        }
    }

    private APIContext Api
    {
        get
        {
            APIContext context = new APIContext(AccessToken);
            context.Config = GetConfiguration();
            return context;
        }
    }

    protected void PostUrl()
    {
        var context = Api;
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", context.AccessToken);

            data = "{name:\"Fruit of the Month\",description:\"10 Pound Box of Fruit\",type:\"fixed\",payment_definitions:[name:\"Standard Package\",type:\"REGULAR\",frequency:\"MONTH\",frequency_interval:\"2\",value:\"50\",currency:\"USD\"},cycles:\"12\",charge_models:[type:\"SHIPPING\",value:\"8\",currency:\"USD\"}},type:\"TAX\",value:\"4\",currency:\"USD\"}}]},name:\"First Month Free Trial\",type:\"TRIAL\",frequency:\"MONTH\",frequency_interval:\"1\",value:\"50\",currency:\"USD\"},cycles:\"1\",charge_models:[type:\"SHIPPING\",value:\"8\",currency:\"USD\"}},type:\"TAX\",value:\"4\",currency:\"USD\"}}]}],value:\"1\",currency:\"USD\"},return_url:\"http://www.fruitofthemonth.com/complete\",cancel_url:\"http://www.fruitofthemonth.com/cancel\",autobill_amount:\"YES\",initial_amount_fail_action:\"CONTINUE\",max_fail_attempts:\"0\"}}";

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string jsonText = serializer.Serialize(data);

                writer.Write(jsonText);
            }

            // The code fails when creating the Response here
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Exception(this.GetType().Name, String.Format("Error: {0}", "Unable to post url."), ex);
        }
```

The code above was simplified just to test the posting/creation of a billing plan in C#.  If anyone has a working example that they can share, please do.

I'm stuck at the moment as I can't figure out what the magic process is to Post for a PayPal Billing Plan against their API.  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Looking at your code, the JSON stored in your `data` value appears to be malformed. For example, `value` and `currency` need to be under an `amount` container in `payment_definitions`, but that appears to be missing.

Comment: As you commented, I was going through line-by-line checking that.  What messed it up was that blog post from the paypal developers (go figure).  I have corrected the JSON and modified the request as there is no more posting error.  Thanks for the double-check!